# Multiple input methods in Lollipop, Bluetooth and Keyboard

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-softkeyboard

I have stumbled into a bit of an issue and am wondering if anyone has hit on a solution?

I am using a nexus 9 on lollipop to test an application, they tab is connected to a bluetooth barcode scanner.

The user has the choice of either scanning a barcode or entering the characters manually be selecting the edittext.

This works fine on any device that is not lollipop, however in lollipop it seems that if the bluetooth scanner is selected as the input method then I cannot get the edittext to pop up a softkeyboard.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it think the scanner is a bluetooth keyboard?  If so that could cause this.  Have you tried forcing the keyboard to show when the edit text is clicked?

Comment: Hi Gabe, Ill be the first to admit I fixed this without really working out how, I was playing around with the settings for the keyboard and I think I switched off hardware emulation for the keyboard and it started working.